# StructureMap default instance and additional with explicit arguments

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap

I've got an interface and a class that implements that interface. That class has a default static instance and can also be constructed explicitly (passing an argument).

How do i configure StrucutreMap so that default instance is the static instance, and if i request an instance with an argument a new one is constructed?

Here's the test that fails

```
[TestFixture]
public class StructureMapTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_same_interface_default_implemenation_and_with_parameter()
    {
        IMyInterface defaultImp = new MyImpl(0);

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                                     {
                                         x.For<IMyInterface>().Use(defaultImp);
                                         x.For<IMyInterface>().Add<MyImpl>().Ctor<int>().IsTheDefault();                                             
                                     });

        Assert.AreEqual(defaultImp, ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyInterface>());

        var instance1 = ObjectFactory.With("value").EqualTo(1).GetInstance<IMyInterface>();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, instance1 != defaultImp); //<-- fails here
        Assert.AreEqual(1, instance1.GetValue());

        var instance2 = ObjectFactory.With("value").EqualTo(2).GetInstance<IMyInterface>();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, instance1 != defaultImp);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, instance2.GetValue());
    }

    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        int GetValue();
    }

    public class MyImpl : IMyInterface
    {
        private int _value;

        public MyImpl(int value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public int GetValue()
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem that you are facing is that when registering multiple implementations for the same interface, the last one is the one that is going to be resolved by GetInstance. To solve this, you could name your configurations.

Try the following:

```
[TestFixture] 
public class StructureMapTests 
{ 
    [Test] 
    public void Test_same_interface_default_implemenation_and_with_parameter() 
    { 
        IMyInterface defaultImp = new MyImpl(0);

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                                     {
                                         x.For<IMyInterface>().Add<MyInterface>().Named("withArgument").Ctor<int>().IsTheDefault();                                        
                                         x.For<IMyInterface>().Use(defaultImp).Named("default");
                                     });

        Assert.AreEqual(defaultImp, ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMyInterface>());

        var instance1 = ObjectFactory.With("value").EqualTo(1).GetInstance<IMyInterface>("withArgument");
        Assert.AreEqual(true, instance1 is MyInterface); 
        Assert.AreEqual(1, instance1.GetValue());

        var instance2 = ObjectFactory.With("value").EqualTo(2).GetInstance<IMyInterface>("withArgument");
        Assert.AreEqual(true, instance2 is MyInterface);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, instance2.GetValue());
    }

    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        int GetValue();
    }

    private class MyInterface : IMyInterface
    {
        private int _value;

        public MyInterface(int value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public int GetValue()
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }
}
```